# Faience GTK theme breaks tabs

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus, themes, faenza

I installed [this theme](http://browse.deviantart.com/art/GTK3-Gnome-Shell-Faience-255097456) in my Ubuntu 12.04 + Unity and all tabs are definitively wrong:

[image]

Any idea to make this theme work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: The theme is clearly stated to **Support Gnome 3.6 only**, 12.04 uses Gnome 3.4, either edit it or get a version for 3.4 of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

In order for tabs and scrollbars to display properly in Precise you will need to update the Unico theme engine (gtk3-engines-unico) from the 1.2.0 version in the standard PPAs.

This PPA has an update that works for me (1.0.2+r139-0ubuntu2~precise1):
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_shell?dist=precise

I suggest not pulling software other than unico from this repo since it proclaims itself to be "bleeding edge" - personally, I added the PPA, upgraded unico, and then disabled the PPA.